# Python Typehinting on a function

Tags: python, python-typing

I have the following python code:

```
foo.create("TireModelA")
```

The function takes as an input a string. There are only 3 options: "TireModelA", TireModelB", "TireModelC".

How can I typehint this in python? I would like that when the user starts to write it suggests the possible completion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two possibilities `Literal` and `Enum`:

```
from typing import Literal
from enum import Enum


class FooParamsEnum(str, Enum):
    tire_model_a = "TireModelA"
    tire_model_b = "TireModelB"
    tire_model_c = "TireModelC"


FooParamsLiterals = Literal["TireModelA", "TireModelB", "TireModelC"]


class Foo1:
    def create(self, param: FooParamsLiterals) -> FooParamsLiterals:
        return param


class Foo2:
    def create(self, param: FooParamsEnum) -> FooParamsEnum:
        return param


foo1 = Foo1()
foo1.create("TireModelA")
foo2 = Foo2()
foo2.create(FooParamsEnum.tire_model_a)
```